# What happens to a GPU multiprocessor's shared memory between kernel block executions?

Tags: cuda, scheduling, gpu-shared-memory

Suppose I have a CUDA kernel with a bunch of blocks, and suppose a some block is scheduled right after another block on the same symmetric multiprocessor (that is, the unit with the same area of shared memory for all warps). NVIDIA does not, at the moment, specify - either in the API or in per-GPU documents - what happens to the shared memory between executions. In practice, though, which of the following holds regarding the block's shared memory contents? :

- It's in the same state the last scheduled block left it.
- It's blank.
- It contains unforeseeable junk.

To narrow down the variation of what might potentially be the case, please refer specifically to the case in which each block uses the maximum possible amount of shared memory - 48 KB on Kepler GPUs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NVIDIA does not publish the behavior of the hardware at this level, so you should consider it as undefined (as @datenwolf says). Though, of course, the contents of the shared memory seen by a given block is not going to be random. And there is no point for the hardware to spend time clearing the memory.

The GPU can run many blocks simultaneously on each SM. The number of blocks that run simultaneously for a given kernel depends on various factors. So, for instance, if shared memory is the limiting factor, each SM will run as many blocks as will fit in shared memory. So, if there is 48K of shared memory and a block needs 10K, 4 blocks may run at the same time, using 40K. So, if you have a device with 8 SMs, my guess is that there will be 32 (4 * 8) possible, fixed, locations for the shared memory of a given block. So, when a new block is scheduled, it will be assigned to one of those locations and see the shared memory as it was left by the previous block that ran in that location.

The API provides no way for a block to detect in which location it is running. Scheduling of a block is determined dynamically and is probably very hard to predict.

If the GPU is used for display, it may be running other kernels (shaders) simultaneously, possibly overwriting the shared memory between blocks in the CUDA kernel in weird and wonderful ways. Even CUDA may be running other kernels behind the scenes.

**Edit:**

I wrote a small program to test things out (included below). The program take the number of integers one block should store in shared memory as an argument. It then launches 100,000 blocks, each with one thread. Each block checks if its shared memory is already initialized. If it's initialized, the block does nothing more. If it's not initialized, the block initializes the memory and increases a global count. The initialization pattern is an increasing sequence of numbers, to avoid having partially overlapping initialized shared memory buffers appear to be valid.

On a GTX660 (Kepler, CC 3.0, 5 SMs), 48K shared memory configured, CC 3.0 Release build, I got the following results:

```
C:\rd\projects\cpp\test_cuda\Release>test_cuda.exe 10000
Shared memory initializations: 5
```

I ran this several times and got the same result each time. This matches the guess I made initially as 10000 integers take up ~40K, so there would be room for one concurrent block per SM, and this device has 5 SMs.

However, when I reduced the shared memory to 2500 integers (~10K), expecting to get 20 initializations, and ran it several times, I got different high numbers:

```
Shared memory initializations: 32,822
Shared memory initializations: 99,996
Shared memory initializations: 35,281
Shared memory initializations: 30,748
```

So, my guess about the fixed locations is completely invalid in this case.

I then tried reducing shared memory to 100 integers (there would be room for 122 blocks in 48K) and consistently got:

```
Shared memory initializations: 480
```

So, again, not the expected number and, surprisingly, there is apparently fewer possible variations even though the amount of shared memory used by each block is smaller.

It looks like, if you are determined to shoot yourself in the foot, you can use a large shared memory block to keep things consistent :) Also, this was run on a GPU that was also used for display, Windows 7 with Aero (A GPU accelerated theme) and it did not seem like rendering would interfere because the desktop freezes while the kernel is running.

Program:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#define assertCudaSuccess(ans) { _assertCudaSuccess((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void _assertCudaSuccess(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line)
{
  if (code != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr,"CUDA Error: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
    exit(code);
  }
}

__global__ void shared_memory_persistence_test(int n_shared_ints);
__device__ int init_cnt_d(0);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  cout.imbue(locale(""));
  int n_shared_ints;
  stringstream(string(argv[1])) >> n_shared_ints;
  shared_memory_persistence_test<<<dim3(100, 1000), 1, n_shared_ints * sizeof(int)>>>(n_shared_ints);
  assertCudaSuccess(cudaPeekAtLastError());
  assertCudaSuccess(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
  int init_cnt_h;
  assertCudaSuccess(cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&init_cnt_h, init_cnt_d, sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
  cout << "Shared memory initializations: " << init_cnt_h << endl;
  return 0;
}

__global__ void shared_memory_persistence_test(int n_shared_ints)
{
  extern __shared__ int shared[];

  for (int i(0); i < n_shared_ints; ++i) {
    if (shared[i] != i) {
      for (int i(0); i < n_shared_ints; ++i) {
        shared[i] = i;
      }
      atomicAdd(&init_cnt_d, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, if the GPU is not used for display, and if I make it the case that only one kernel is executing (not as trivial as it sounds, but not impossible), and if each block is willing to pay the price of putting its id in shared memory, the next block might be able to tell which kernel was last.

Comment: @einpoklum: from a language point of view this is undefined behaviour, and that is all you ever need to know...

Comment: If it can potentially save me copying 48KB of data from shared to global memory and back, then I _definitely_ need to know more than that. Just think about what this could do for reductions... where even identifying the previous block is unnecessary.

Comment: tbe point is that the  execution order and hardware affinity are undefined. Accessing memory which is defined but uninitiated at the current scope is undefined behavior. Writing code which deliberately relies on any undefined behavior is just plain stupid

Comment: @einpoklum: It's undefined behavior and **you must never base your code's behavior on some corner case expectations of how undefined behavior turns out. Never!**. All it takes is a small change in the system which makes your code break. Heck maybe what you're developing works only on your machine, but on other GPUs its broken, because you're (unintentionally) rely on a silicon bug that got fixed in a later revision.

Comment: @datenwolf: It's only undefined unless someone tells me how it _is_ defined. If you don't know, then ok. I was asking since I'm assuming it is defined, just not part of any official spec. And please don't shout.

Comment: @einpoklum: Undefined means *there is no definition*. It means that nobody did bother to investigate it, or write down what's going to happen. Heck if you asked the CUDA developers at NVidia themself they'd probably tell you "we don't know what will happen". This is exactly what *undefined* means. There is no defined behavior. Period. End of discussion. No matter how hard you try to find some sense in it, the next time only a small detail changes (different motherboard, other driver version, heck even a different program running) a different thing may happen.

Comment: @einpoklum: Also often things are left open and undefined deliberately, so that implementations have some leeway in which they optimize and rearrange things without having to care about those explicitly putting certain things into a certain state. In fact many compilers optimization is based on certain things being undefined and hence not allowed to be done in a program which gives the compiler some leeway in the knowledge of what the programmer may not expect from the environment he's working in. This is a fact about undefined behavior you simply have to accept and there's no way around it.

Comment: @datenwolf: Perhaps you're right. But - we don't know that. Maybe it's undefined merely because NVidia did not want to commit to how this might change in future GPUs. Maybe nobody bothered to put it in the spec. Maybe the behavior is ugly and complex. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: @einpoklum: Yes, those are very valid reasons to leave this undefined. But that doesn't mean that there somewhere a "secret" or "implicit" definition you could rely on. It doesn't matter *why* certain things are undefined. The only thing that matters is that they *are* undefined, which essentially puts a bright, red tape on it with **"do not make use of or rely on it in any way"** written on it in very bold lettering.

Comment: [Example of what might happen when you depend on UB](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/918) - and, which is possibly more important, why it happens (it's for gcc 4.8 but the principle is the same) in a way that is intuitive for humans (who have much bigger reasoning capability then compilers and understend the meaning of code and what is _supposed_ to happen).

Answer (score 1):

The state is undefined. Which mean it could be anything, including the anything of the three things you guessed. But reading from uninitialized memory could lead into your GPU emerge an artificial intelligence as well.

Comment: @einpoklum: That question is impossible to answer as the behavior may change with every driver version or even may depend on the system hardware configuration in which the GPU has been put into.

Comment: Asking for someone to give you a definition of undefined behavior strikes me as a very odd question indeed.  Kudos to these individuals willing to take a crack at answering it.